# How can I do an image sequence with a theme of nature (plants, flowers, etc.)?

Tags: nature

I am in beginners photography a class that my school offers and I am in my final project. My teacher said we can pick a theme for our project and I chose to do an image sequence with the theme of nature (plants, flowers, etc.) the only problem is that I am so new to this and don't really know how to go about doing this since my teacher wants me to shoot more than 10 scenes but my series must have 5 final images. Can anyone please help me? It will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you pick nature if you find it hard to create images with that subject? What motivated that choice?

Answer (score 7):

"Nature (plants, flowers, etc.)" is so broad and nebulous, that it sounds like you're just trying to make up a subject that you think might be easy, but as you don't *know* much or are interested in nature (plants, flowers, etc.), nothing's occurring to you.

I'm a nature (landscape, wildlife, plant macro) photographer because I *like* and am interested in nature. I do online research to identify birds and plants and bugs and read about what's local to me just because I find it fun and fascinating. I take pictures of birds or plants to identify or celebrate seeing them. I just spent an hour the other day rambling about in a back canyon to visit a patch of California roses *(Rosa californica)* I know about, just to see if I could catch them in the early part of their bloom cycle (I did. It was a good day). I love these roses because they're native species (uncultivated/unbred) roses, and California is one of the last places you'd expect to have one--unless you're a rose-lover/grower. The flowers are small and pink, about the size of your thumbnail and single (i.e., only has five petals).  I got one shot of a bud just unfurling, and another of a full bloom.  When the hips come in, I'll probably photograph those, too.  And that will tell the story of the lifecycle of the bloom.  A story I find endlessly fascinating and like to tell/show.

Many would find it *very* boring.  But not to **my** eyes. To my eyes those tiny pink flowers have meaning and drama.

Generally, you pick a topic/theme that's a subject you're *already* interested in. If you're not interested enough in a topic to want to shoot it 10 different times/ways, maybe you need to come up with a different topic. What do you love? And why? What fires your imagination? What stories do you want to tell? What's important to you?  What do you know a lot about?

That is most likely to be a good photography subject for your project.

Comment: While I think this is a great answer (and great recommendation about finding subjects and themes), I feel like it fails to answer this particular question. Maybe the selected topic cannot be changed now, or other readers may not have selected similar topic for themselves. Maybe you could provide a bit more info on where to start, or what areas of "nature" photograpy are approachable for newbies?

Comment: @J.E I'm not sure I can, as that's pretty much all I've got on how to begin an approach on any subject (i.e., ask yourself, "what do I care about?"; thus, for nature, what do I care about when it comes to nature?). Have you considered adding your own answer to approach from a different direction?

Comment: I have considered, but feel like I don't have much of value to say, not experienced in this. It seemed like you could have some more inspiration, since you are obviously very passionate about the subject. But that is ok :-)